# How can women live without Testosterone

Tags: testosterone, sex

I read that [men experience degraded fitness under testosterone deficiency](http://www.howlifeworks.com/Article.aspx?Cat_URL=health_beauty&AG_URL=How_to_Quickly_Boost_Your_Testosterone_for_Increased_Performance_441&ag_id=1275&wid=8D1C83BD-80E8-471B-9187-548A78A36894&did=6537&cid=1005&si_id=2584). There are ways to support it in norm. But what about the woman. How can they stay so vivid at much lower testosterone levels? Do they have different (muscle/brain) tissue responsiveness to the testosterone?

Comment: An interesting inquiry, but doesn't seem to be on topic re specific fitness questions/problems.

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to clarify a very important point: both men and women have testosterone and estrogen, however the proportions and functions are different in each.  An article on whether ["BioSignature" holds water against science](http://bayesianbodybuilding.com/biosignature-reviewed-hormones-key-weight-loss/) had some interesting facts regarding the role of testosterone and estrogen in men and women:

- In men, testosterone is the primary counterbalance to cortosol.  Additionally, the body will manufacture the estrogen it needs from testosterone.
- In women, estrogen is the primary counterbalance to corotosol.  Additionally, the body will manufacture the testosterone it needs from estrogen.

The hormonal profile between men and women are different, and the effect they have on the body is profound.

- Women tend to handle endurance better than men
- Men tend to handle tasks that require more power output (i.e. moving heavy objects, etc.)

NOTE: [women also have skeletal differences](http://gregnuckols.com/2013/07/17/do-women-need-to-train-any-differently/) that do affect the weight they can handle, and what constitutes proper form.

There are some similarities as well:

- Muscle behaves the same in men and women.  Given the same cross-sectional mass of muscle, and the same neural efficiency, men and women will be able to move the same weight.  The hormonal differences prevent a woman from gaining the same cross-sectional mass of muscle with the same duration and quality of training.
- Women can, and should, train in much the same way as men do.  Certain movements will be easier to progress in than others.  For example, pressing is more difficult compared to deadlifting for women.

Bottom line is this: both men and women's physiologies are fundamentally different.  Women simply don't need the same amount of testosterone as men to function properly from a physiological standpoint.  They aren't going to develop the same moodiness, lack of sleep, depression, and other ailments common with low testosterone in men.  Also note that all a "natural testosterone booster" can do is bring low testosterone closer to normal levels.

Comment: In summary, you say that they can because they can. This is a bit circular argument (I did not get how cortosol, ednurance, power and muscle/skeletal differences allow to women to maintain fitness at lower testosterone levels). Yet, compared with the first answer, it is a wisdom itself.

Comment: The body will manufacture the testosterone it needs.  Men and women are physiologically different, and the body's requirements for the hormones in question are different.  I hope that much is clear.  If you are asking why men and women are different that's a fundamentally different question not suited for a fitness focused Q&A site.

Comment: @Berin Loritsch, could you please forward me a link of how to boost testosterone naturally. Sine I have so many contradict natural foods.